# Filter Sub array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, linq.js

i am trying to filter my array which has a sub array.
i want to filter my array by sub array
my array looks like this:

```
 var Branches = [
            {
                Name: 'branch1',
                Screens: [
                    {
                        Name: 'Screen1',
                        Player: {
                            Status: 0
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        Name: 'Screen2',
                        Player: {
                            Status: 1
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                Name: 'branch2',
                Screens: [
                    {
                        Name: 'Screen1',
                        Player: {
                            Status: 0
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        Name: 'Screen2',
                        Player: {
                            Status: 1
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }]
```

i've tried this using linq.js

```
var param = 1
var result = Enumerable.From(Branches).Where(function (d) {

                return (d.Screen.some(x => x.Player.Status === param))

            }).ToArray();
```

but this code olso gets the status 0 from each branches

i want to get only the status = 1 from each branches

Expected out :

```
[
            {
                Name: 'branch1',
                Screens: [
                    {
                        Name: 'Screen2',
                        Player: {
                            Status: 1
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                Name: 'branch2',
                Screens: [
                    {
                        Name: 'Screen2',
                        Player: {
                            Status: 1
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }

        ]
```

Thanks ;)

Comment: what if you have no `Status: 1` inside? do you want to get the parent object? or just the filtering of the inner arrays?

Comment: yes i want to get the parent object along with childs wich has filtered

Comment: @NinaScholz hi any other solution for this? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could map the objects and filter `Screens`.

```js
var branches = [{ Name: 'branch1', Screens: [{ Name: 'Screen1', Player: { Status: 0 } }, { Name: 'Screen2', Player: { Status: 1 } }] }, { Name: 'branch2', Screens: [{ Name: 'Screen1', Player: { Status: 0 } }, { Name: 'Screen2', Player: { Status: 1 } }] }],
    wanted = 1,
    result = branches.map(({ Screens, ...o }) => ({ ...o, Screens: Screens.filter(({ Player: { Status } }) => Status === wanted) }));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks this is what i looking for. , can you explain the syntax '...o' is for what?

Comment: `...o` takes the rest of the object without destructured properties.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Branches = [
  {
    Name: "branch1",
    Screens: [
      {
        Name: "Screen1",
        Player: {
          Status: 0
        }
      },
      {
        Name: "Screen2",
        Player: {
          Status: 1
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    Name: "branch2",
    Screens: [
      {
        Name: "Screen1",
        Player: {
          Status: 0
        }
      },
      {
        Name: "Screen2",
        Player: {
          Status: 1
        }
      }
    ]
  }
];
var param = 1;
console.log(Branches.reduce( (p, c) => ((c.Screens = c.Screens
    .filter(s => s.Player.Status == param)).length && p.push(c), p), []
));
```

Comment: i got error :  fis not define, i tried replacing it by p but i got nothing :(

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: i used Google Chrome

Comment: hi may branches Screens was remove after the first filter. ex: i want the status : 1, in the next filter i want status: 0 , but all status : 0 was removed?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't understand the question?

Comment: ow sorry , i mean in my first filter status: 1 i got correct result , but when i filter status : 0 i got nothing, when i look my branches all screens with status: 0 was remove

Comment: Strange, I do get results.. 

Answer (score 0):

Using linq.js, you need to view it as selecting branches with a filtered set of screens. You probably don't want to modify the existing items so you should create new ones.

```
let status = 1;
let result = Enumerable.From(Branches)
    .Select(({Screens, ...rest}) => ({
        Screens: Enumerable.From(Screens)
            .Where(({Player:{Status}}) => Status === status)
            .ToArray(),
        ...rest
    })).ToArray();
```

Though Nina shows, you don't really need this as `Array.map` and `Array.filter` can handle this.